# How are sine and cosine used for collision detection?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I'm working through a tutorial to make the old arcade game Breakout - you have a paddle at the bottom of the screen and the goal is to deflect a moving ball into a series of blocks at the top of the screen.

The code to calculate the rebound effect is:

```
ball.dx = ball.speed * Math.sin(angle);
ball.dy = - ball.speed * Math.cos(angle);
```

The yellow circle represents the ball:

[image]

I understand sine and cosine as ratios of the hypotenuse; I just still can't seem to grasp how they are used to calculate the rebound angle here exactly. Can anyone explain how the resulting numbers, given an angle and a speed value, produce the directionality of the ball on rebound? I feel there's a simple conceptual piece of the puzzle I'm missing.

Comment: They're not being used to calculate the rebound angle; the angle is an *input* to what you've shown. They're being used to calculate the two sides of the rectangle given that angle, as you say using the trigonometric relationship with the hypotenuse.

Comment: Reading the Newtonian mechanics chapter in an elementary physics book will help you a great deal.

Comment: There are several ways of defining the functions cos and sin. The one you need here is the unit circle one. See for example: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:trig#x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:unit-circle

Comment: My understanding after having spent some time thinking about this is that the angle as an input provides the means for calculating the Y value (`ball.dy`) and and the X value (`ball.dx`). These two resulting values, as coordinates, provide the means for programmatically moving the ball across the canvas. Because the JavaScript function returns a value between -1 and 1, the resulting movement effect would be rather slow, so we multiply by the hypotenuse, `ball.speed` to increase the rate at which the ball moves. Am I in the ballpark?

Answer (score 0):

This is vector adding - the X and Y vector added give you the new speed value.
To easier understand how sin and cos work here, take the case of angel = 0 deg. The ball falls straight down, and should bounce back up:

```
ball.dx = ball.speed * Math.sin(0); // 0
ball.dy = - ball.speed * Math.cos(0); // 1
```

So there's no movement left or right, speed is the same but the vertical direction is reversed because of the minus sign.

Using sin and cos here takes care of having a constant speed, as well, as these always sum up to 1.

Hope that's a bit more clarifying than confusing, but I did some similar code tasks that got easily solved with basic vector operations.

Comment: `these always sum up to 1` not exactly, it's a bit trickier than that. What you do get is a constant hypotenuse - which means the speed doesn't change, but that doesn't mean the same thing as `sin(x) + cos(x) = 1` or `dx + dy = constant`. What's constant is `sqr(dx) + sqr(dy)`.

Comment: Conservation of momentum is the key idea here.